# The difference between com.mysema.query and com.querydsl?

Tags: querydsl

I am a newbie in querydsl.
I saw two types of querydsl implementations.

Is there any differnece? I already developed with com.mysema.query implementation. 
But I think I went wrong way. Please explain about this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`com.querydsl` is the root package for Querydsl 4.* and `com.mysema.query` is the root package for Querydsl 3.*.

The background is that Querydsl was initially owned by [Mysema](http://www.mysema.com), but is now owned and mantained by the [Querydsl team](http://www.querydsl.com/team).